# App works fine on main account but crashes with System.UnAuthorisedException on secondary account

Tags: android, exception, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to track down what is causing this issue on an Android app I am developing. I am running Android KitKat and I have a Nexus 10 with 2 accounts on it.

I am also using the Monodroid framework provided by Xamarin, so I am not using the Native Android SDK.

Whenever I run it through the main account it starts up without any problems.

However when I run the app through the secondary account.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "data/myApp/files" is denied.
```

This happens when the `CreateDirectory()` function is called.

Can anyone give me a hint as to why this is doing this? I am stumped because all of the permissions I have on the manifest are enabled (from writing/reading to external storage) , as I said before it works great on the primary account of the Nexus 10, but not on the secondary account.

many thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you creating that directory? There should not be any problems with this. One thought is to install the app as the other user and see if it does the same thing. If it persists, it might be a bug in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Hi, we are using the functions from the System.IO namespace. 

Yeah I have already tried installing the app in the secondary account and it throws the same error, also tried compiling using a higher API level.

So fair chance it could be a bug.

Comment: Hey, managed to get it working, we were using hardcoded RootPaths instead of using... 

Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal))

works great now :)